# How to implement Ben Alman's debounce jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debouncing

I'm using this project: https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce

My code is -sorta- working, but the debounce is being ignored.
So the waterfall function is called on every image load but the 2 second delay is not being respected. No errors are being shown.

What is the correct way to implement this?
I've been fiddling with this for 3 hours now, but can't find a solution.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(e) {

    var $waterfall = $('.waterfall');
    if ($waterfall.length) {
      $waterfall.waterfall({});
    }

    // sort the waterfall when images are loaded
    var $waterfall_images = $waterfall.find('img');
    $waterfall_images.each(function(j, image) {
      var $img = $(image);

      $img.load(function() {
        $.debounce(2000, $waterfall.waterfall('sort'));
      });

    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<ul class="waterfall">
  <li class="waterfall-item">
    <a href="hidden link" title="hidden title">
      <img alt="hidden alt" title="hidden title" data-srcset="hidden in this example" data-src="also hidden in this example" src="still hidden in this example" data-sizes="(min-width:440px) 300px, 95vw" class=" lazyloaded" sizes="(min-width:440px) 300px, 95vw"
      srcset="think I'll hide this one too">
      <span class="waterfallImgOverlay"></span>
    </a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method, not assigning a reference. Easiest thing, wrap it in a function. Second thing is debounce returns a method, so you need to store what it returns and than call that method.

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(e) {

    var $waterfall = $('.waterfall');
    if ($waterfall.length) {
      $waterfall.waterfall({});
    }

    var waterfallSort = $.debounce(2000, function(){ $waterfall.waterfall('sort'); });

    // sort the waterfall when images are loaded
    var $waterfall_images = $waterfall.find('img');
    $waterfall_images.each(function(j, image) {
      var $img = $(image);

      $img.load( waterfallSort );

    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It still doesn't respect the delay ...
It loads the first set of images after about 500 MS, 2nd set after another 500 MS and 3rd and last set of images after another 500 MS. While the delay is set to 2 seconds and even if I set it much higher it doesn't change anything.

Comment: There fixed it.